# Util.prompt_for_user_token() method isn't running

Tags: jupyter, spotify, libspotify, spotify-app

I'm attempting to run a util.prompt_for_user_token() method but the method is taking forever to run. I'm running it from the gcollab jupyter notebook.

I am using the code found in the spotipy documentation.

```
util.prompt_for_user_token(username=Username,
                           scope=Scope,
                           client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                           client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                           redirect_uri=Redirect_uri)
```

Comment: Can you please add more detail on how are you running this or a scenario that can be replicated?

Comment: Yes! I first created this .ipynb file by using gcollaboration's web application. 

Here is a snippet of my full code: https://photos.app.goo.gl/YrSeDhwEbTper4NC8.

Comment: Additionally, the problem seems in be in the redirct_uri parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out there is a problem with spotipy on the gcollab platform. The code above works perfectly fine in visual studio Code. I'll continue to research why spotipy isn't functioning well and will add more information when I do.